# Program design architecture for sensors application in embedded device

Tags: c++, architecture, arduino

I'm not an expert with C++ since I come from an electronics background.

I'm trying to make a Arduino program that allows anyone to add a sensors easily to a Arduino device using a standard format.

I thought of making a HAL for each sensor, for that I have created a class named `Sensor` which is the base class for each sensor. The user has to create a subclass that inherits from the `Sensor` class. This subclass for example is called `Sensor_2` (2 is the ID) and it implements functions like:

```
uint16_t getID( void );
uint8_t getAvailableChannels( void ); 
void sampleChannel( uint8_t aChannel, uint8_t *aDataSize, uint8_t aDataBuffer[] );
```

This class is the one that calls its own sensor library which is dependent of the sensor.

Doing it this way I can sample every sensor in an standard way without having to rewrite each sensor library.

I don't know if that is the way to do it but I can't think of anything better.

I have tried to implement that with the following code:

Sensor.h

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H

#include "Arduino.h"

class Sensor
{
public:
  Sensor();  
  virtual uint16_t getID( void );
  virtual uint8_t getAvailableChannels( void ); 
  virtual void sampleChannel( uint8_t channel, uint8_t dataSize, uint8_t dataBuffer[]);
};

#endif
```

Sensor_2.h

```
#ifndef Sensor_2_H
#define Sensor_2_H

#include "Arduino.h"

#include "../../Sensor.h"

#define ID 2
#define CHANNELS 1
class Sensor_2: public Sensor
{
public:
  Sensor_2 ( void  );  
  virtual uint16_t getID( void );
  virtual uint8_t getAvailableChannels( void ); 
  virtual void sampleChannel( uint8_t aChannel, uint8_t *aDataSize, uint8_t aDataBuffer[] );
};

#endif
```

Sensor_2.cpp

```
#include "Sensor_2.h"

Sensor_2::Sensor_2( void )
{

}

uint16_t Sensor_2::getID( void )
{
    return (ID);    
}

uint8_t Sensor_2::getAvailableChannels( void )
{
    return (CHANNELS);    
} 

void sampleChannel( uint8_t aChannel, uint8_t *aDataSize, uint8_t aDataBuffer[] )
{
    aDataSize = 1;
    aDataBuffer[0] = hallRead();    
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Logger.h>
#include "ComHandler.h"    
#include "./Sensors/Sensor_2/Sensor_2.h"


ComHandler comHandler;

SensorManager* sensorManager = SensorManager::getInstance();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Logger::setLogLevel(Logger::WARNING);

  Sensor_2 sensorHall = new Sensor_2;

  sensorManager->addSensor(sensorHall);     
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t* datasize;
    uint16_t buffer[4];
    comHandler.checkForData();
    sensorManager.getAvailableSensors()[0].sampleChannel(0,dataSize, buffer);

}
```

The problem is that when trying to compile I get this error:

```
conversion from 'Sensor_2*' to non-scalar type 'Sensor_2' requested
   Sensor_2 sensorHall = new Sensor_2;
                         ^
```

If instead of:

```
Sensor_2 sensorHall = new Sensor_2;
```

I use:

```
Sensor_2 sensorHall;
```

I get:

```
sketch/Sensor.cpp.o:(.literal._ZN6SensorC2Ev+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for Sensor'
sketch/Winja.ino.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0x10): undefined reference to `Sensor_2::Sensor_2()'
sketch/Winja.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup()':
```

Do you think this is a good way to implement a solution to my problem? If so, how could I fix my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem, here you have two issues (one is blocking, the other not).

As for the simplest problem, `Sensor_2 sensorHall = new Sensor_2;` is not valid, since the `new` keyword generates a pointer to the object. You have two ways to generate an object and to pass it to the sensor manager (I assume the sensor manager accepts pointer to sensors):

```
// Solution 1
Sensor_2 *sensorHall = new Sensor_2;
sensorManager->addSensor(sensorHall);

// Solution 2
Sensor_2 sensorHall;
sensorManager->addSensor(&sensorHall);
```

Please note, however, that if you use solution 2 you must put the sensor definition outside the function. If, for instance, you write

```
void setup() {
  Sensor_2 sensorHall;
  sensorManager->addSensor(&sensorHall);
}
```

then the sensor object will be destroyed after you exit the `setup`. In order to avoid this, write

```
Sensor_2 sensorHall;
void setup() {
  sensorManager->addSensor(&sensorHall);
}
```

As for the main problem, I think that arduino does not compile source files outside the main sketch folder (and it does not recursively, so subfolders are not scanned).

However, what you are trying to do is usually done by implementing libraries. You can find different libraries and resources to understand how a library work (for instance, there is a [library tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) on the arduino website). You will have to create a folder inside the library folder, then put inside the source files (in this case you can use subfolders); the compilation will be successful. This way you won't need to copy these files in future projects: they will already be there.

If you don't want to make them shared, and still want to put them in a separate folder, IIRC you can make a special folder called src and put the source files there (again, not in subfolders). The src folder gets merged with the sketch folder when compiling.

My suggestion: make it a library. Fully reusable, easy to maintain, even a bit of highlighting...

Comment: Thank you for all your time . I will try that. I don't think I want to make this a library since it is very specific to my problem. What do you think of the way I want to implement this? Would you do it in any other way?

Comment: @Twistx77 Well, if you are putting some effort in order to make it "universal", so that a lot of different sensors can be used, then it is exactly the reason why libraries are invented. Even if, for now, it is just one project which uses them. As for the implementation, no, I think you did your job in the correct way (define a common interface and a way to identify the different members). In my projects instead of a numeric ID I usually use enums to identify the children, so it is more "user friendly"

Comment: Moreover I don't know what is your specific task, but I usually prefer to have some specific members for the children. For instance, I want a generic `sampleChannel` which returns a byte array, but I also want a more specific `getDistance` for the ultrasonic sensor, a `getTemperature` for the temperature or a `setSampleRate` for an ADC, so if I know that the third element of SensorManager is a temperature sensor I can cast it and then get directly the physical quantity (so the conversion is done in the class, and not in the main)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I will try to give you the big picture of what I'm trying to acomplish. I'm trying to make a board that will be able to connect to almost any sensor. It has 4 connectors and all of them have a I2C bus, and two of them also have ADC inputs and digital I/O, DAC and one of them SPI. The Idea is to make it so anyone can make a board for the type of connector I'm using and then simply writting the Sensor_X class which interfaces between the main app and your sensors library(More specific of course). The main app will be able to interface with the sensor with almost

Comment: Not modifications. Moreover, by making a text based file it will be able to be interfaced with a computer/ mobile software that tells the software the ID, range of the sensor, conversion operation (ADC reading to Temperature), it will give it also a way to configure it where all the parameters are in the text file so you don't have to modify the software or the main app in the firmware. From the software you will be able to ask to the device just the ID's of the sensors availables and the software will have in the text file all the data necessary to interact with the sensor in question.